# SpEL expression with String list fails to be evaluated

Tags: acl, spring-el

*Update on Oct 27*

The following method has a SpEL based ACL annotation. It's meant to check whether the file object of `fileId` has permissions of `Read` and `Write`. If the file object contains any of the two permission, the ACL passes, otherwise, it throws an exception.

```
@Component
public class ApiImpl {
    @PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
    public FileListVO getFiles(String fileId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The annotation is through `acl` component below.

```
public interface AclService {
    boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext);
}

@Component("acl")
public class AclServiceImpl implements AclService {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext) {
        List<String> resourcePermissions = get permissions of resource
        if (resourcePermissions contains any of permissions) {
            return true;
        }
        throw exception here
    }
}
```

The question is, the SpEL expression below fails to be evaluated:

```
@PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)'
There is a List<String> permissions in it. What is the correct expression for this?
```

Please note that the `throw exception` behavior in `AclServiceImpl.hasPermissions()` is legacy code which I don't want to change. `@PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")` is expected to return `true` not throw exception. I know the following could be an option,

```
public interface AclService {
    boolean hasPermission(String type, String permission, Object resource, Object... resourceContext);
}

@Component("acl")
public class AclServiceImpl implements AclService {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(String type, String permission, Object resource, Object... resourceContext) {
        List<String> resourcePermissions = get permissions of resource
        if (resourcePermissions contains permission) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; // not throw exception
    }
}

@Component
public class ApiImpl {
    @PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File','Read', #fileId)"
        + "|| @acl.hasPermissions('File','Write', #fileId)")
    @PostMeetingTelemetry()
    public FileListVO getFiles(String fileId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I just wonder how to enhance

```
@PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
```

so that the following code works.

```
public interface AclService {
    boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext);
}

@Component("acl")
public class AclServiceImpl implements AclService {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext) {
        List<String> resourcePermissions = get permissions of resource
        if (resourcePermissions contains any of permissions) {
            return true;
        }
        throw exception here
    }
}

@Component
public class ApiImpl {
    @PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
    public FileListVO getFiles(String fileId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following changes, it works. Not sure the 1st change is required, but the 2nd change is a must.

1. Replace `List<String>` with `String[]` for `permissions`
2. Replace `{'Read','Write'}` with `new String[]{'Read','Write'}`

### Before

```
public interface AclService {
    boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext);
}

@Component("acl")
public class AclServiceImpl implements AclService {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermissions(String type, List<String> permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext) {
        List<String> resourcePermissions = get permissions of resource
        if (resourcePermissions contains any of permissions) {
            return true;
        }
        throw exception here
    }
}

@Component
public class ApiImpl {
    @PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
    @PostMeetingTelemetry()
    public FileListVO getFiles(String fileId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

### After

```
public interface AclService {
    // Replace List<String> with String[]
    boolean hasPermissions(String type, String[] permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext);
}

@Component("acl")
public class AclServiceImpl implements AclService {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermissions(String type, String[] permissions, Object resource, Object... resourceContext) {
        List<String> resourcePermissions = get permissions of resource
        if (resourcePermissions contains any of permissions) {
            return true;
        }
        throw exception here
    }
}

@Component
public class ApiImpl {
    // Replace {'Read','Write'} with new String[]{'Read','Write'}
    @PreAuthorize("@acl.hasPermissions('File',new String[]{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")
    @PostMeetingTelemetry()
    public FileListVO getFiles(String fileId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> throw exception here

Of course the evaluation fails if you throw an exception there.

You should return false instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Gary! What I'm actually asking is posted below.

Comment: You should not add an answer to clarify the question; edit the question instead. The simplest solution is to write a wrapper bean around the existing ACL bean that catches the exception and returns false. It is not possible to catch the exception in SpEL itself. `@PreAuthorize("@aclWrapper.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")`.

Comment: The question is updated. Just wondering how to enhance `@PreAuthorize("@aclWrapper.hasPermissions('File',{'Read','Write'}, #fileId)")` ...

I know `@PreAuthorize("@acl.hasResPermissions('PostMeeting', new String[]{'Read','CO_Read'}, #meetingUUID)")` doesn't work either, but what's the correct format?

Comment: What you have works fine for me, SpEL builds a List<String> for the second argument. I tested it as pure SpEL though, (not in spring security) but that shouldn’t make a difference. If you are still having issues I will take a look tomorrow.